# R vs SQL - loading only some data from db

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I'm using this code for load only id that are in my df.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl(conn, "table") %>%
  filter(idvar %in% df$id) %>%
  select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
  collect()
```

The question is how to use that with joining and another criteria like on code below, but still load only that matched ids - there are milions ids in my db but in my df are only hundreds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.id = table.id
WHERE date > "2010-01-01" and column3 is not null
```

Comment: just do the join with `dplyr` (using `dplyr::left_join`) before using `collect`, or just send your query as is through `DBI::dbGetQuery`

Comment: Would you olease explain more widely that second option - DBI::dbGetQuery?

Comment: try `result <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT ...")` where `SELECT ...` is the query you typed above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you with little workaround.
I have tried with similar scenario and it worked for me.
Note : I didn't try using dplyr. 
I have used My-SQL as db and [DBI](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/) & [pool](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pool/versions/0.1.0.9000) are the R packages.

```
library(DBI)
library(pool)
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "db_name",host = "host_name",username = "User_name", password = "password", port = 3306, unix.sock = "/path/to/mysqld/mysqld.sock")
```

In the above line at `unix.sock` i gave My_SQL socket path because i've encountered a problem without it. To get the socket path:
`mysql_config --socket` (ubuntu)

```
users <- lapply(df$id, function(x){
  dbGetQuery(pool, paste0("SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.id = table.id 
                          WHERE table.user_id IN('", x,"');" ))
})
```

Please edit the SQL query according to your requirement till `WHERE` condition.
It fetches from database as a list. Process that list as per your requirement.